# A few standard results (on metrizability and relative separation strength) without choice?

Tags: general-topology, reference-request, axiom-of-choice, alternative-proof, separation-axioms

I've been going back over some results from Munkres's *Topology*, and I'm curious about some things....

I know that Choice principles have *some* connection to the separation axioms (in ZF, at least)--for example:

> Locally compact Hausdorff spaces are Baire if and only if the Axiom of Dependent Multiple Choices holds. [Due to Fossy and Morillon, I believe.]
>
> Complete pseudometric spaces are Baire if and only if the Axiom of Dependent Choices holds.

Still, it seems likely that compactness (or the weaker condition of completeness) and "Baireness" may be playing a substantial part, here.

The link provided below by dfeuer shows that the Urysohn Metrization Theorem--which states that regular, Hausdorff, second-countable spaces are metrizable (or equivalently, that a space is separable and metrizable if and only if it is regular, Hausdorff, and second countable)--holds in ZF, though the Urysohn Lemma--which states that a space is normal Hausdorff if and only if any two disjoint closed sets can be separated by a continuous function--does not. That's a nice result.

I have two questions, then.

First, I wonder if it is known how little Choice is needed for the Urysohn Lemma to hold--the usual proof (cf. Munkres) uses Dependent Choice, and Andreas has suggested that Dependent Multiple Choices may do the trick. Is it known if we can do with even less Choice than that? Is it possible that the Urysohn Lemma is equivalent (in ZF) to some other known Choice principle?

Second, I wonder what is known about how much Choice is needed to prove the following metrization theorems, or whether any of them are known to be equivalent in ZF:

> **Nagata-Smirnov Metrization Theorem**: A topological space $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is [$T_3$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_Hausdorff_space) and has a basis that is countably locally finite [= $\sigma$-locally finite base].
>
> **Smirnov Metrization Theorem**: A topological space is metrizable if and only if it is [paracompact](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paracompact_space) Hausdorff and locally metrizable.
>
> **Bing Metrization Theorem**: A topological space $X$ is metrizable if and only if it is $T_3$ and has a basis that is countably locally discrete [= $\sigma$-discrete base].

Comment: Ask and ye shall receive, some: http://web.mat.bham.ac.uk/C.Good/research/pdfs/horror.pdf indicates that some choice is required for Urysohn's Lemma, but not for Urysohn's Metrization Theorem.

Comment: I'd suspect that Bing and Nagata-Smirnov are equivalent in any model, but I'd have to check the proofs. In the text I learnt these from, they were merged into one theorem (Bing-Nagata-Smirnov) as a three-way equivalence.

Comment: @dfeuer: Interesting. Thanks!

Comment: Dependent multiple choice suffices for Urysohn's Lemma.  The idea is that, instead of choosing single open sets at each step to interpolate between previous choices, you can choose finitely many open sets and then intersect them.  (If I remember correctly, it was David Pincus who pointed out to me that Multiple Choice suffices for Urysohn's Lemma; it's a small step from there to see that Dependent Multiple Choice also suffices.)

Comment: @Andreas: Multiple Choice is equivalent to Choice in ZF (unless we're talking about two different things), so that doesn't seem like a small step to me, but perhaps I'm missing something. Care to clarify?

Comment: He said dependent multiple choice, not multiple choice.

Comment: David's observation works in set theories with atoms, where Multiple Choice is weaker than full Choice.  Also, as dfeuer pointed out, Dependent Multiple Choice is not known (to me) to imply Dependent Choice.  (I expect the Howard-Rubin book has a counterexample, but I have neither the book nor much time at the moment.)

Comment: @Andreas: I believe it is still an open question whether DC and DMC are equivalent in ZF.

Comment: My observation? I only observed the text in front of me...

Comment: @dfeuer: Andreas mentioned both Multiple Choice *and* Dependent Multiple  Choice. Also, I believe he was referring to David Pincus's observation. Is that you, by chance?

Comment: No. I may have misread... My name is David....

Comment: To prove some other choice principle from Urysohn's lemma would seem to require some way to produce lots and lots of sufficiently-complex (non-discrete, to begin with) normal spaces. I don't know how to do so (especially without any choice), but I'm just an undergrad.

Comment: Regarding Smirnov, I once read an exceptionally straightforward proof by Mary Ellen Rudin that metric spaces are paracompact. Said proof (easily found online) invokes the well-ordering theorem on the very first line.

Comment: @dfeuer: That may just be a matter of convenience, rather than necessity. Still, the fact that so many of these proofs tend to involve Choice is precisely the reason that I ask this question.

Comment: This was reposted on MO: http://mathoverflow.net/questions/137152/a-few-standard-results-on-metrizability-and-relative-separation-strength-witho

Comment: @Martin: Thank you. Should've thought to post a link, myself.